# getting router log routing ERROR [7f258b169700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74) while connect and close using mysqlsh

Tags: mysqlrouter

getting below error while connect and close using Mysqsh with socket file for every min.

Details:
mysql version: 8.0.32
router version: 8.0.32
shell version: 8.0.32
OS version: centos 7

error in router log:

2023-02-09 16:00:01 routing INFO [7f258c18c700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] incrementing error counter for host of /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock (now 0)
2023-02-09 16:00:01 routing ERROR [7f258c18c700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74)
2023-02-09 16:02:01 routing INFO [7f258b169700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock closed connection before finishing handshake
2023-02-09 16:02:01 routing INFO [7f258b169700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] incrementing error counter for host of /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock (now 0)
2023-02-09 16:02:01 routing ERROR [7f258b169700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74)
2023-02-09 16:04:01 routing INFO [7f258a167700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock closed connection before finishing handshake
2023-02-09 16:04:01 routing INFO [7f258a167700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] incrementing error counter for host of /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock (now 0)
2023-02-09 16:04:01 routing ERROR [7f258a167700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74)
2023-02-09 16:06:01 routing INFO [7f2589144700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock closed connection before finishing handshake
2023-02-09 16:06:01 routing INFO [7f2589144700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] incrementing error counter for host of /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock (now 0)
2023-02-09 16:06:01 routing ERROR [7f2589144700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74)
2023-02-09 16:08:02 routing INFO [7f258c18c700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock closed connection before finishing handshake
2023-02-09 16:08:02 routing INFO [7f258c18c700] [routing:bootstrap_rw] incrementing error counter for host of /opt/mysqlrouter/mysql.sock (now 0)
2023-02-09 16:08:02 routing ERROR [7f258c18c700] classic::loop() processor failed: Bad message (generic:74)

Why this error getting ? is any way to fix this error ?

Comment: This error is  getting from only 8.0.32 router version . not for 8.0.31 version. i am not sure we are hitting any bug for this version ?

Comment: any one any update ?